# Concatenate and use multi line variable in multi line curl execution

Tags: bash, shell-script, curl

With this code

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
PROPERTIES="MAINTAINER=Self, My"

while IFS='=' read -r key value
do
  ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS+="-F variables[${key}]=${value} "
done <<< "${PROPERTIES}"
#ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS="$(echo -e "${ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS}" | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"

curl -k -X POST -F token=TOKEN -F "ref=master" \
-F "variables[GIT_REF]=GIT_REF" \
-F "variables[GIT_COMMIT]=GIT_COMMIT" \
${ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS} \
https://gitlab.url.net
```

I'm trying to pass multiple unknown properties as build parameters to a GitLab pipeline.

The problem seem to be the generated quotes at the wrong position leading to the following call and error:

```
+ curl -k -X POST -F token=TOKEN -F ref=master -F 'variables[GIT_REF]=GIT_REF' -F 'variables[GIT_COMMIT]=GIT_COMMIT' -F 'variables[MAINTAINER]=Self,' My https://gitlab.url.net
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'My'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'gitlab.url.net
```

Where do the single quotes come from and why is the second quote in the middle of the variable? `-F 'variables[MAINTAINER]=Self,' My`

Comment: `"${ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS[@]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *really* need to use arrays for this sort of thing: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

```
#!/bin/bash
properties="MAINTAINER=Self, My"

curl_opts=(
    -k 
    -X POST 
    -F token=TOKEN 
    -F "ref=master" 
    -F "variables[GIT_REF]=GIT_REF" 
    -F "variables[GIT_COMMIT]=GIT_COMMIT" 
)

while IFS='=' read -r key value; do
    curl_opts+=( -F "variables[$key]=$value" )
done <<< "$properties"

curl "${curl_opts[@]}" https://gitlab.url.net
```

This code is not only correct, but IMO is much easier to read.

Also, don't use ALL_CAPS_VARNAMES: consider those as reserved by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

`set -x` added the single quotes, to make the output reusable.

You need to quote `${ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS}` as `"${ADDITIONAL_PARAMETERS}"` otherwise it is subject to word splitting and filename expansion.  Word splitting happened to you:

```
variables[MAINTAINER]=Self, My
```

was split into:

```
variables[MAINTAINER]=Self,
```

and:

```
My
```

as it was passed to the `curl` command.